# Lowest degree of a coefficient in a chromatic polynomial for a simple connected graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Ok so I know a chromatic polynomial can't ever have a constant term, but why is the lowest degree of a coefficient in a chromatic polynomial for a simple connected graph always 1?

Is there a simple explanation for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a proof here at the bottom of the page:

http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m4408/gtln6.htm

The idea of the proof is very simple: You prove by induction on the number of edges that the lowest degree is exactly the number of components.

The inductive step is based on the following observation:

If you remove a bridge, then the lowest term in $G \backslash e$ has the degree equal with the number of components of $G$ while the lowest term in $G-e$ has the degree one more than the number of components of $G$.

If $e$ is not a bridge, then the lowest term in $G \backslash e$ and the lowest term in $G-e$ have the degree exactly the number of components of $G$.
Now, the alternating of the signs tell you that their coefficients have opposite signs, so they cannot cancel in the difference...